# Binning sequence reads by GC content

Tags: bioinformatics, sequences, fasta

I would like to "bin" (split into separate files) a multi-fasta nucleotide sequence file (e.g. a Roche-454 run of ~500,000 reads average read length 250bp). I would like the bins based on GC content of each read.
The resultant output would be 8 multi-fasta files:

<20%  GC content

21-30%  GC content

31-40%  GC content

41-50%  GC content

51-60%  GC content

61-70%  GC content

71-80%  GC content

>80 %  GC content

Does anyone know of a script or program that does this already?
If not can someone suggest how to sort the multi-fasta file based on GC content (that I can then split it down into the relevant bins)?

Comment: Edited the tags to remove 'garbage-collection'. No, I unfortunately have no clue how to easily help you - no tool I know off the top of my head. I do know the scope of the project and would be willing to work with you if you need any help.

Comment: GC means guanine-cytosine. That is, analyse a text file, compute a metric on it, and sort / bin by the metric.

Comment: Could you perhaps give us a sample of the file format? I know what a sequence in a Fasta file looks like (just capitals), but what do the reads' headers look like, and are there any new lines separating entries?

Comment: python? R? C?  if you want advice on how to do this yourself, what programming language do you prefer?

Comment: This question is perhaps a better fit for http://biostars.org

Answer (score 2):

In R / Bioconductor, the tasks would be (a) load the appropriate library (b) read the fasta file (c) calculate nucleotide use and gc % (d) cut the data into bins and (e) output the original data into separate files. Along the lines of

```
## load
library(ShortRead)
## input
fa = readFasta("/path/to/fasta.fasta")
## gc content. 'abc' is a matrix, [, c("G", "C")] selects two columns
abc = alphabetFrequency(sread(fa), baseOnly=TRUE)
gc = rowSums(abc[,c("G", "C")]) / rowSums(abc)
## cut gc content into bins, with breaks at seq(0, 1, .2)
bin = cut(gc, seq(0, 1, .2))
## output, [bin==lvl] selects the reads whose 'bin' value is lvl
for (lvl in levels(bin)) {
    fileName = sprintf("%s.fasta", lvl)
    writeFasta(fa[bin==lvl], file=fileName)
}
```

To get going with R / Bioconductor see http://bioconductor.org/install. The memory requirements for 454 data of the size indicated are not too bad, and the script here will be fairly speedy (e.g., 7s for 260k reads).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Python and [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython) or Perl and [Bioperl](http://www.bioperl.org/) to read in the FASTA-files. There is a script that calculates C-content of sequences in Bioperl [here](https://github.com/bioperl/bioperl-live/blob/master/scripts/seqstats/gccalc.PLS), and Biopython has a [function for it](http://www.biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils-module.html#GC). Then simply store the GC content for each sequence in a dictionary or hash and go through each, writing them into a file dependin on how high the GC-content is.

Do you need any more specific help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need something like the following (Python):

```py
def GC(seq): # determine the GC content
    s = seq.upper()
    return 100.0 * (s.count('G') + s.count('C')) / len(s)

def bin(gc): # get the number of the 'bin' for this value of GC content
    if gc < 20: return 1
    elif gc > 80: return 8
    else:
        return int(gc/10)
```

Then you just need to read the entries from the file, calculate the GC content, find the right bin and write the entry to the appropriate file. The following example implements this with a Python [package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyteomics) we use in the lab:

```py
from pyteomics import fasta

def split_to_bin_files(multifile):
"""Reads a file and writes the entries to appropriate 'bin' files.
`multifile` must be a filename (str)"""

    for entry in fasta.read(multifile):
        fasta.write((entry,), (multifile+'_bin_'+
                    str(bin(GC(entry[1])))))
```

Then you just call it like `split_to_bin_files('mybig.fasta')`.